# I am trying to create a program that counts lines after inputting \n. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: c

I am learning C programming through the Kernighan & Ritchie book, and adapted their code a bit in to create my own program. Only I am getting after the input of one character three lines of output. The first two lines say amount of lines is 0 and then amount of lines is 1. I would obviously rather have that the input goes to one directly. What am I doing wrong?

```
int main()
{
    int stor, lines;
    lines = 0;
    while((stor = getchar()) != EOF){
        if(stor == '\n')
            ++lines;;
         printf("Amount of lines:%d\n", lines);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: What's your input? But anyway, you can easily debug your program by printing out the ASCII code of the lat character received. Like `printf("Amount of lines:%d, last char=%x\n", lines, stor);`

Answer (score 2):

You print out the number of lines inside of the `while` loop, which runs for *each character* you input.  So for each key you press, you get a line of output.

Move the `printf` to after the body of the `while` loop, and it will print only once at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int stor, lines;
    lines = 0;
    while((stor = getchar()) != EOF) {
       if(stor == '\n')
            ++lines;
    }
    printf("Amount of lines:%d\n", lines);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to count the total number of new line characters `\n` in your input.

For this you need to print the total number of `\n` only after you are done processing the input. So, you need to move the `printf` outside your while loop.

```
int main()
{
    int stor, lines;
    lines = 0;
    while((stor = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if(stor == '\n')
        ++lines;

    /* Move the below printf outside the while loop */
    /* printf("Amount of lines:%d\n", lines); */
    }

    printf("Amount of lines:%d\n", lines);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: okay that answered my question fully thank you. Then i have to press the EOF to get to the statement i assume, since then the while loop terminates?

Comment: yes an EOF is needed for the while loop to terminate. In unix type system you can pass EOF by `Ctrl+D`, and in windows you can do it by `Ctrl+Z`. However if you are redirecting input from a file you do not have to do anything, EOF is automatically read at the end of file.